# Makefile only executes when file name is passed to it (C)

Tags: c, makefile

I have a very simple makefile, makefile.mak , that isn't being recognized by the makefile command.

When I enter "make mp3" Makefile spits out "No rule to make target 'mp3'. Stop."

However when I enter "make -f makefile.mak mp3" the command executes fine. Why is this?

```
mp3: addMP3.c deleteAllOccurOf.c deleteMP3.c main.c printBackward.c printForward.c
    gcc -o mp3.out addMP3.c deleteAllOccurOf.c deleteMP3.c main.c printBackward.c printForward.c
```

Comment: @user3386109 I never thought the extension would be the issue, thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, since that worked for you, I posted it as the answer :)

Comment: The ways `make` finds makefiles are well-documented in the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, a makefile is called `makefile`. In other words remove the `.mak` from the filename.